# Flurry clips (video ads) integration for Android

Tags: android, flurry

Is it possible to integrate video ads from Flurry in an android app? I tried some things, but it didn't work. The Flurry Android SDK has the `onVideoCompleted` function, and in the Android Flurry SDK Release Notes, the following can be found: `verified support for clips in AdUnity` (http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/Code/ReleaseNotes/Android).

I tried this code, but it didn't work for me:

```
package com.test.flurrytest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.flurry.android.FlurryAdType;
import com.flurry.android.FlurryAds;
import com.flurry.android.FlurryAdSize;
import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent;
import com.flurry.android.FlurryAdListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdCallbackListener, FlurryAdListener  {
FrameLayout mBanner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mBanner = new FrameLayout(this);
    FlurryAds.setAdListener(this);
    FlurryAds.enableTestAds(true);

     Button watchvideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.watchvideo);
     watchvideo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FlurryAds.fetchAd(MainActivity.this, "TestAdspace", mBanner, FlurryAdSize.FULLSCREEN);
            FlurryAds.displayAd(MainActivity.this, "TestAdspace", mBanner);
            }
     });
}
// Flurry

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "****");
}

public void spaceDidReceiveAd(String adSpace) {
    FlurryAds.displayAd(this, adSpace, mBanner);
}

public void onVideoCompleted(String adSpace) {
    // The user get some points now
}

public boolean shouldDisplayAd(String adSpaceName, FlurryAdType type) {

    return true;
}
public void onAdClosed(String adSpaceName) {


}

public void onRenderFailed(String adSpaceName) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The video has failed to render. Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void onApplicationExit(String adSpaceName) {


}
public void spaceDidFailToReceiveAd(String adSpaceName) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to receive ad. Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void onAdClicked(String adSpaceName) {


}

public void onAdOpened(String adSpaceName) {


}



@Override  
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    FlurryAds.removeAd(this, "TestAdspace", mBanner);
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
}
}
```

Is it possible with Android, and if so, how to integrate it?

Thanks!